# Draw Ontop Of Image Control In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I am working on porting over an old WinForms project to WPF but have hit a brick wall. In this old WinForms project, I am using a picture control that is painting an image every second. Along with that, I have the controls 'Paint' event overridden to draw custom things on top of the image once it is already set.

So for example my code flow is something like:

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Load("some/image/path");
}
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    // do custom drawing on top of the picture here..
}
```

WPF offers no direct 'Paint' event so I'm unsure how I should be properly porting this over to WPF and still keep an MVVM pattern.

So my question(s) would be:

- Is using an Image control the proper method for this setup?
- How should I go about recreating this similar setup in WPF where I can update the image as needed, then draw things on top of it.

*My intent is to keep with an traditional MVVM pattern but still be able to draw onto the image after it is loaded. All the drawing is done from inside the application, there is no user interaction to the drawing. I am basically drawing a map with points of interest on top of the map image in real time. The map is static and not broken into pieces like Google's tiles and such so I have no issues with just loading directly from disk.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a clean MVVM aproach you could use an ItemsControl with a Canvas as `ItemsPanel` and a Path control in the `ItemTemplate`. The Path control binds to an appropriate set of view model properties which define the visual appearance of the drawings.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Drawings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Geometry}"
                  Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                  Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                  StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The view model could be something like this:

```
public class Drawing
{
    public Geometry Geometry { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
    public Brush Stroke { get; set; }
    public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Drawing> Drawings { get; set; }
}
```

It might be used like shown below.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.Drawings = new ObservableCollection<Drawing>();
    vm.Drawings.Add(new Drawing
        {
            Geometry = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 100), 50, 30),
            Fill = Brushes.LightBlue,
            Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
            StrokeThickness = 2
        });
    vm.Drawings.Add(new Drawing
    {
        Geometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(50, 150, 100, 60)),
        Fill = Brushes.LightGreen,
        Stroke = Brushes.Green,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    });

    DataContext = vm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright after a lot of tinkering around I figured out a suitable method for my needs. Using a canvas control and exposing it to my viewmodel I can draw various objects to the canvas to replicate the WinForm style of the drawing.

So for anyone else looking for a similar work around, I recommend a canvas control.